# AWS S3 Node.js - Set Content-Disposition for object

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I searched a lot on the internet about this but couldn't find a solution.
I'm using pre-signed URLs to give the user the ability to upload files to S3.
But, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
export const getSignedUrlForUpload = async (destFilePath) => {
    const s3 = getS3Object({ signatureVersion: 'v4' });

    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: destFilePath,
        ContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename=data.jpg',
        ACL: "public-read",
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
```

In order to make the file downloadable with my desired name.
It doesn't work.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Key` parameter?

Comment: I used it before, but I faced a problem with file names with hebrew chars and spaces, so I prefer to generate id for the key and when the client downloads the file it will have a proper filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work already as it is, I have tried with a regular `putObject` (the `getSignedUrl` supports the same parameters) and here are the results.

I upload the object:

```js
const params = {
  Bucket: 'my_bucket',
  Key: 'MDSD.pdf', // This could be anything with standard chars
  Body: fileContent,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentDisposition: 'attachment; filename=test.pdf',
};

s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
});
```

On the S3 Console it looks like this:
[image: screenshot of AWS S3 Console - Metadata section]

If we check the object info via AWS CLI it looks like this:

```sh
aws s3api head-object --bucket my_bucket --key MDSD.pdf
// output
AcceptRanges: bytes
ContentDisposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
ContentLength: 5067743
ContentType: application/pdf
ETag: '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
LastModified: '2020-11-26T15:59:02+00:00'
Metadata: {}
```

If I try to download the file with `wget`, using the `--content-disposition` flag, you can see that the suggested filename is respected:

```sh
wget https://my_bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/MDSD.pdf --content-disposition
// output
--2020-11-26 17:00:32--  https://my_bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/MDSD.pdf
Resolving my_bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com... 10.119.74.124
Connecting to my_bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com|10.119.74.124|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5067743 (4.8M) [application/pdf]
Saving to: 'test.pdf'

test.pdf            100%[===================>]   4.83M  8.85MB/s    in 0.5s    

2020-11-26 17:00:33 (8.85 MB/s) - 'test.pdf' saved [5067743/5067743]
```

I have also made another test, this time using exactly your code and then trying to upload a file programmatically with the axios library:

```js
const getUrlAndUpload = async () => {
  // Get Url (your code)
  let presignedUrl = await getPresignedUrl();

  // Read content from the file
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('any_name.pdf');

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf',
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    },
  };

  let response;
  try {
    response = await axios.put(presignedUrl, fileContent, options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log(response);
  process.exit(0);
};

console.log(getUrlAndUpload());
// {status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: {…}, config: {…}, request: ClientRequest, …}
```

The important detail (I also stumbled in this while testing) is that while uploading you need to specify **always** the same parameters you're signing + add the `x-amz-acl` one that in this case is `public-read`. If for instance you add `Content-Type` while signing the URL, then you'll have to set `Content-Type` also in the headers of the upload request.

Comment: So when adding the ContentDisposition to the params, the content-disposition header is added to the X-Amz-SignedHeaders list in the signed url. But when trying to PUT the object from the browser, i'm getting 403 Forbidden as a response from s3.

Comment: You're right, I have updated the answer with another example to show that you need to put the correct headers to the `PUT` request.